# Will using recovery disk overwrite later changes to partitions?

Tags: windows-7

Suppose I have created a recovery disk for Windows 7 from recovery partition on the hard drive.

When I have to recover from he recovery disk sometime in the future, will the recovery overwrite the changes to the partition and installation of a later OS which happened later than the creation of the recovery partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I suppose I cannot answer your Question with absolution; I do not use Windows for Back-up or Recovery however the very essence of recovering information is to completely wipe the slate clean and use what was working before.

You can however with other software Restore certain files; so for example if you do a complete scan on your system and it is clean, you then disk clean, defragment and what ever else then create a Back-up of your system; you find two weeks later that Tetris has a virus you can't get rid of but you've installed some new programs and customized your login profile so you don't want to do a clean Recovery; you can go into your back-up and restore just the Tetris data.

The Key to sucessful back-ups however....... is Back-up, Back-up, Back-up.  Especially if your system changes; that is precicely to avoid this issue; chances are Tetris won't hold the virus for long!

Good luck hope that helps.